# Symfony admin generator-- a button for save and back to list

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-forms, symfony-1.4, admin-generator

How can I add a ***save and back to list*** button in the view for creating new record? In general, I want more buttons so I'm looking for a generic answer.

EDIT: Default generator provides me with two buttons:

> 1. ***save***
> 2. ***save and add***

I want a button that `saves and takes me back to the list`. And I also want a custom button with a custom action.

Let me explain the actual situation:

I have a list action `create` that takes me to a form having some input fields. Now I want to make an image using these fields' data. I want to display this image as preview on the right side of the form. For that I need a preview button so that whenever pressed, it submits the data to itself for preview and further modification.

I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Could your explain better your question? **Save** and **Back to list** button are enabled by default in a form. Where do you want insert more buttons? Do you need also buttons with custom action?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have first to add in `generator.yml` your `save_and_back_to_list` and other custom `my_other_action` actions:

```
    config:
      actions: ~
      fields:  ~
      list:    ~
      filter:  ~
      form:    ~
      edit:
        actions:
          _save: ~
          _list: ~
          save_and_back_to_list: ~
          my_other_action: ~
      new:
        actions:
          _save: ~
          _save_and_add: ~
          _list: ~
          save_and_back_to_list: ~
          my_other_action: ~
```

Then you have to add your customized helper functions to create your buttons in `/apps/myapplication/modules/mymodule/lib/mymoduleGeneratorHelper.class.php`

```
  public function linkToSaveAndBackToList($object, $params)
  {
    return '<li class="sf_admin_action_save_and_back_to_list"><input type="submit" value="'.__($params['label'], array(), 'sf_admin').'" name="save_and_back_to_list" /></li>';
  }

  public function linkToMyOtherAction($object, $params)
  {
    return '<li class="sf_admin_action_my_other_action"><input type="submit" value="'.__($params['label'], array(), 'sf_admin').'" name="my_other_action" /></li>';
  }
```

Now you get two submit buttons both in `New` and `Edit` form.

Finally you have to override the function `processForm(sfWebRequest $request, sfForm $form)`, that you can find in `/cache/dev/modules/autoMymodule/actions/actions.class.php`, to manage your new submit actions. I guess your `create` function overrides the admin generator one.

I hope I don't forget nothing.

Comment: actually my `create` is not overriding the default one, I'll change the name to something else. but I got the idea.

Comment: The actions provided by the admin generator starts with an underscore, but not in action class. I guess that this Symfony rule has as purpose to get a separation from user actions.

Comment: I thought I should make it a separate question. My actual situation: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8445441/symfony-alternate-new-action

Comment: Also, When I looked up the source of `/mymodule/new`, I saw the submit action of the form is `/mymodule` instead of `/mymodule/create` as in the _Jobeet_ tutorial. If it is so, then how does it end up calling `executeCreate`?

Comment: Good question! I guess that the routing system switches to the action create for post request if the form action is not specified. I don't know the reason for this choice.

Comment: Also about your new question, I'm dealing with this matter (think I'm developing an extension of the admin generator as plugin), both image upload and admin forms customization, and I will answer hoping and trying to well focus what you need.

Comment: well, now I understand how does it end up calling executeCreate. The output of `./symfony app:route backend` tells me that for url `/poster/`, a `GET` or a `HEAD` request corresponds to `index` action and a `POST` request corresponds to `create` action. Weird though.