# Symfony alternate new action

Tags: php, symfony-forms, symfony-1.4, admin-generator

I have a server where I need to store some images. Now the images can be either uploaded or created on the fly let us say just by adding some text to some default picture(So I made a file  `MakenewForm.php` for that) . The table in my database stores filename on the local filesystem. Now upload is simple, I can just use the default _new action for that. For creating picture, I made a new action, say `makenew`. `new` and `makenew` both are diplayed on the list view. I copied `newSuccess.php` to `makenewSuccess.php`. Now I want a different set of submit buttons for them. I can't seem to figure out how to do that. All I see is this:

```
<div id="sf_admin_content">
<?php include_partial('poster/form', array('poster' => $poster, 'form' => $form,       'configuration' => $configuration, 'helper' => $helper)) ?>
</div>
```

I don't know what is $configuration and what is $helper. Can someone tell me about them? Which one do I need to change and How?

Also, as you can infer, the submit action of the `new` action only needs to do a `$form->save()` but the submit action of `makenew` needs to take all the text input and write an image file(let's say using ***imagejpeg***)

I need some pointers towards achieving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope to well focus about what you are looking for.

About `$configuration` and `$helper`, as you can find in `cache\mypplication\dev\modules\autoMymodule\actions\actions.class.php` the function `preExecute()` is used also to create them:

```
$this->configuration = new mymoduleGeneratorConfiguration();
$this->helper = new mymoduleGeneratorHelper();
```

These classes are in `apps\docdesk\modules\mymodule\lib`. You can find base classes in `cache\mypplication\dev\modules\autoMymodule\lib`. Have a look to these base classes to understand how are used and so which configuration functions and helper functions the admin generator makes available.

To deal with your new action, I don't know the feature you're developing so I'll try to imagine two possible scenarios. You can use only a form switching your functions of upload/create picture trough a custom widget, overriding the template `_form.php`, called in your snippet, and the new action and so on or, this is the way you're following, create a completely separate action, form and all needed templates. So in your makenewSucces.php you can include a template _makeform.php called with

`<?php include_partial('poster/makeform', array('poster' => $poster, 'form' => $form, 'configuration' => $configuration, 'helper' => $helper)) ?>`

Of course you have to put the template `_makeform.php` in `apps\docdesk\modules\mymodule\template` as each new or overrided one.

I don't well understand your trouble about the image saving... I suppose you're asking for the saving chain of an image and how and where you can manage what you need.
To add the widget to upload an image inside your `PosterForm` class you can use a snippet like this where we suppose `photo` as widget name, according with a schema field `photo:              { type: varchar(255), required: true }`, that is of course to customize:

```
    public function configure()
    {
        $photo = $this->getObject()->getPhoto(); // get the photo name
        $photo = sfConfig::get('sf_upload_image_dir').$photo;

        $this->widgetSchema['photo'] = new sfWidgetFormInputFileEditable(array(
            'label'     => 'Photo',
            'file_src'  => $photo,
            'is_image'  => true,
            'edit_mode' => !$this->isNew(),
            'delete_label' => 'check to remove',
            'template'  => '<div>%input%<br/><br/>%file%<br/><br/>%delete%<p>%delete_label%<br/><p></div>'
        ));

        $this->validatorSchema['photo'] = new sfValidatorFile(array(
            'required'   => true,
            'path'            => sfConfig::get('sf_upload_image_dir'),
            'mime_categories' => array('web_images' => array(
                'image/jpeg',
                'image/pjpeg',
                'image/png',
                'image/x-png'
            )),
            'mime_types' => 'web_images',
        ));

        $this->validatorSchema['photo_delete'] = new sfValidatorPass();
    }
```

Note that my setting for `upload_image_dir` is `%SF_UPLOAD_DIR%/images/`

Symfony will upload and save the image for you!

Then you can override the `doSave` function, according to your needs, putting the same one yet in your `PosterForm` class:

```
protected function doSave($con = null)
{
    $delete = $this->getValue('photo_delete');
    if ( $delete )
    {
        // ...
    }

    $upload = $this->getValue('photo');
    if ( $upload )
    {
        // ...
    }
    return parent::doSave($con);
}
```

Finally to remove your image, that is the file, when you delete the object, that is the db record where the image name is a field, you have to put this code in your model class `Poster`:

```
public function delete(PropelPDO $con = null) // using Propel
{
    $photo = sfConfig::get('sf_upload_image_dir').$this->getPhoto();
    if ( file_exists($photo) )
        unlink($photo);

    return parent::delete($con);
}
```

I hope this can help you.